# Greatest common Divisor asking is this logic is correct?

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

The correct and most efficient way to calculate Greatest common divisor
its common question to ask in beginner coding interview

void function that returns nothing just taking 2 parameter from user and calculate its greatest common divisor.

```
    public static void Greatest_Common_Divisor(int a, int b){
        int gcd=1,i=2;

        while(true){
            if(a%i==0 && b%i==0){ // checking both the number is divisible by i
                gcd=gcd*i;        // if yes multiply gcd value
                a=a/i;
                b=b/i;
                if(a%i!=0 || b%i!=0){ // divisible incrementing i by 1
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Greatest Common Divisor :"+gcd);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What results do you get when you test it?

Comment: I would check the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) on Wikipedia...

Comment: @user85421 Great suggestion, I found it to be a good read and after comprehending how the algorithm works was able to find a very simple recursive solution. Though I quickly discovered it would need some fine-tuning if negative or 0 values are allowed.

Comment: No, your algorithm won't work.  If you try to take the GCD of any two odd numbers, your algorithm returns 1, which is clearly not right.

Comment: @Calvin There is an [Implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations)  section on the Wikipedia page, including a change "If negative inputs are allowed"

Comment: @user85421 Touché, I had neglected to read that far.